# Android studio 2.2 build error

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm using Android Studio 2.2; when I try to build any project I am getting the following error:

```
Error:Could not initialize class com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.xs.SchemaDVFactoryImpl
```

I get this error even when try samples projects. Does any one know reason for this error?

Comment: Can you include the code that affects the error you are receiving.